# Get Subtotal, Discount, Tax, and Total for this address at multiple addresses overview

Tags: magento2, php, checkout, multiple-checkout

How could I get the data for `Subtotal, Discount, Tax, and Total for this address` at multiple addresses overview checkout like at picture below?

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**=> Try to use this code :**

```
$_address->getSubtotal(); //get the subtotal
$_address->getGrandTotal(); //get the total for this address

$_address->setSubtotal($value); //set the subtotal
$_address->setGrandTotal($value); //set the total for this address
```